# Is REST mandatory for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am beginning on ASP.net MVC. All the articles I have read so far mention REST as a key feature in MVC implementation
My question: is REST mandatory for MVC implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  You can use any url scheme you want.  MVC just makes doing REST much easier than WebForms.